# Is it possible to have two main() methods in the same class?

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

Can I have two main method in a class?

```
public TwoMain{
    public static void main(){
        //some code
    }

    public static void main(){
        //some code
    }
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from testing it yourself?

Comment: The right time to answer this question is that I don't have laptop on those days. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just test it yourself and see what happens? Nothing will blow up. And it's much more **fun** to do so!

I tried this on my editor and of course, it did not compile. In fact, you cannot write any duplicate methods, no matter what they are called. So you cannot have two `foo()` methods, two `bar()` methods, two `iAmHandsome()` methods, or two `sweeperRocks()` methods in one class.

But you can declare *overloads* of a method. An overload of a method X is a method with a method with a same name as method X, but with different parameters.

For example, this is a `foo` method:

```
public void foo () {}
```

This is an overload of `foo`

```
public void foo (int i)  {}
```

Now we can say that `foo` has two overloads.

Comment: Excellent answer to a garbage question. +1

Comment: it is easy to do so what if it is public static void main(String[] args) and public static void main(String arg).

Comment: sorry public static void main() not public static void main(String arg)

Comment: As I said just try and see what happens! @Sachin